# How to do a safe (and deterministic) update of an object instance?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Assume that I have a `foo` object that has a private instance `bar` of class `Bar` (which implements `IBar`). `bar` is accessed through a public property exposing only `IBar`.

Occasionally, my application would get notified of some DB changes that trigger a need to update `bar`. So I create a new instance `bar2` of `Bar`. Now, I need to replace `bar` with `bar2` inside `foo`.

Is there a well-known idiom/pattern to do this update such that my application has a deterministic response to it? Basically, certain parts of the code would continue to use the old `bar` but not start a new operation, for example, until `bar` has been updated.

For instance, I maybe able to use something like an update token (similar to a cancellation token) that various parts of my application would check at certain points to wait for the updated object. But before I go too far in that direction, and start thinking of performance implications, I want to know if there is a well-established means of achieving what I want.

Note: I already know that a reference update is atomic, and that my code will always access *a* bar object. That's not my question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on if you are keeping references  to `bar` around outside of the `foo` object or if you are grabbing a reference for each operation only at the time of that operation. If every time you need to use `bar` you call the public property directly and don't cache that property result in the callers and you only use `bar` within `foo` using the public property (basically, every access is guarded by the same piece of code), then you can just lock in that accessor and also in the method that updates `bar`. This means that once the update is queued, it will not take place until it can lock out all other uses of `bar` and those uses will wait until they have a new `bar` to work with.

```
public class Foo
{
    private static object _barLock = new object();
    private IBar bar;
    public IBar Bar
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_barLock)
            {
                return bar;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_barLock)
            {
                bar = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateBar(IBar bar2)
    {
        Bar = bar2;
    }

    public void DoStuffWithBar()
    {
        Bar.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

You can get more complicated but efficient with the locks, but the main idea is as long as you encapsulate the access to `bar` and standardize on that everywhere without allowing consumers to hold on to old references, you can control the update and usage sequence with simple locks.

Note that because of the way the above is constructed, operations within `bar` would not be influenced by the locks, so they could continue to run on the old instance of `bar` while it is being replaced by `bar2`, but callers making the next call against `Bar` would use the new instance for subsequent operations. If I understood your question correctly, that's the behavior you're looking for.

If you can't prevent the consumers from holding on to reference to `bar`, don't expose it and instead wrap it in another object that guards it by passing calls through to it without letting the callers know it exists. That way you can standardize again with the accessor locks.

Keep in mind that you will want to be sure you are properly disposing of the old `bar` instances when you are finished with them (after they have been replaced and any calls currently in progress have completed). Otherwise you will end up with a memory leak.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. But only if every access to `bar` is an atomic operation. However, I have, for instance, a state machine that accesses `bar` at various points during its execution. Each run of the state machines represents an operation. I would want an already running operation to continue with old `bar` but only new transactions use the new `bar`.

Comment: I should probably then keep a `bar` reference for every instance of the state machine. And use what you suggested for other parts of the code.

Comment: In other words, you want to have higher level transactions that use the same reference all the way through regardless of when `bar` changes but you want new transactions to use the new `bar`? If so, I misunderstood and will need to update the answer a bit.

Comment: State machines with a potentially infinite life-spawn or a single set of calls that you want to all use the same `bar` instance once started?

Comment: Assignments of classes and interfaces are atomic, there is no need to lock around the `bar = value;` or `return bar;` if you mark the `bar` variable volatile.

Comment: @S.C. We can assume it's a single set of calls. I say "assume" because some of them are periodic in nature. But, every period, it's as if the state machine is restarting .. hence, the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

`foo.getBar()` returns `IBar`. Then people do some `bar.doBaz()` and expect consistent results before and after  replacement.

If you can gurantee that no code will cache a copy of bar (unlike the example above) then you have hope. Otherwise if someone keeps a copy of `bar` with them then you have a difficult time ahead.

If everyone always does `foo.getBar().doBaz()` then things should be fine in every cases except when multiple threads are involved. If you suspect multiple threads, or parallel requests in web/service, then you have two ways. (1) use `lock` in `getBar()` and `private setBar`. This is the recommended approach. (2) Locks cause a *little* slowdown. You can use `volatile` on the private bar field, instead of using locks. BUT, beware, volatile is the least understood and most misunderstood beast.

If you want ALL bar instances to magically get upgraded, then you can look at proxy pattern. Idea is, along with `class Bar : IBar`, have a `class BarProxy : IBar`. Within `foo.getBar()`, dont `return _bar`, but `return new BarProxy(this)`. Capture the parent `foo` instance within BarProxy. Then for each of the implemented methods, like doBaz(), perform `return _foo._bar.doBaz()`. This way the moment you replace the bar inside foo, all the barProxys will start relaying calls to the new bar.

### Edit

If if do `getBar()` twice and get two different bars *and* whether the two bars behave the same or not depends on whether there was a silent switch somewhere, then this is going to be a very confusing implementation. You are going to kill a few interns. If instances of bar are supposed to behave differently then I recommend having a `BarFactory`. So every client code (state machines) will consciously `create` their own bars bases on their own initial state. This will eliminate confusion on who has what bar.

Comment: Good answer. To expand a bit on one of your points, one way to guarantee that no one caches a copy of `bar` is to not actually expose it in the first place and just create a wrapper/passthrough to expose instead since can be sure the passthrough does not cache it.

Comment: I am typing on an android phone so came late to the party!

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment here, there are certain operations (state machine instances) that once triggered should continue with the old instance of `bar` that they have started with. New operations should use new `bar`. Accordingly, allowing getting a reference to `bar` is inevitable in my case.

Comment: Do you actually mean a state machine or do you mean a linear sequence of calls? I can't tell from your comments but both would have differing implementations.

Comment: An FSM that uses frequent calls to `bar`. Each instance of that FSM should use the same instance of `bar` it started with.

Comment: In that case, @inquisitive's suggestion of a factory pattern is very much in line with what you want. Let the state machine be constructed through a factory that manages `bar` instances in the ways suggested earlier. Don't update existing state machines when `bar` changes but newly created ones will use the new instance of `bar` because that's what the factory managing `bar` tells them to do. That definitely complicates the stale `bar` instance disposal mechanism, though.

Comment: Why not create the state machine instances through `foo` and pass a copy of `bar` to each state machine instance? In that case, old instances work fine. New state machine instances get the updated copy of `bar`. And when all instances using the old `bar` expire. Nobody is pointing to the old `bar`, and it gets disposed of gracefully.

Comment: Only reason I could think to contest your point is that the lifetime of bar is critical to the system. That makes construction and destruction of bar a critical aspect. By SOLID principles, foo should not bear this extra responsibility. Let a factory do that. So there will be no confusion on which instance does what and is owned by whom.